# Set of probability generating functions complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

A probability generating function of a possibly defective distribution is a function

$f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i $,

for which

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\leq 1$.

Let $C$ be the set of all functions $f$ satisfying the above. Is it then true that $C$ is a Banach space (i.e., it is a complete normed vector space, which means that Cauchy sequences are convergent). If yes, with respect to which norm?

Comment: You should be more precise about what you call "complete set". Isn't it a complete basis in a Hilbert (not only normed) space ?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about complete bases, but about complete spaces. I clarified my question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The class of generating functions of sub-probability distribution on non-negative integers is not a vector space. However, it is a complete metric space: we can identify generating functions with the coefficient sequences. The set of sequences under consideration is a closed subset of the complete space $l^1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... correct me if I'm wrong: (1) If I would drop the requirement that the sequences add up to at most 1, then the set $C$ is identifiable with l1 and it would be a vector space (and hence it would be a Banach space).
(2) The metric that we use in $C$ is simply the l1-metric of the related elements in the l1 space.

Comment: Well, even if you drop the upper bound there is a restriction that the coefficients have to be non-negative and the set is not a vector space. If you allow negative coefficients also then you do get a Banach space with the $l^1$ norm but the space is not related to what you call generating function!